# Ubuntu 18.04 set locale to Hebrew

Tags: 18.04, locale

I'm using PuTTY and I've created locale following guides, and something just not working there..

I used commands like `localectl set-locale LANG=he_IL.utf8 LANGUAGE="he_IL:he"`

Running test afterwards of `localectl` command shows the values has been updated correctly, but when I upload files in Hebrew, the files are blank and only file extension is remained.

Also used `sudo locale-gen he_IL.UTF-8` but after running `locale` command `LANG` parameter didn't changed, I don't understand why though.

I have entered `nano .bashrc` and exported `LANG` parameter with my locale value, I think it suppose to work.

How to set correctly Ubunto language locale system to Hebrew so it can receive Hebrew files name?

[Uploading files in Hebrew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY70C.png)

[File Manager result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8piIC.png)

EDIT:

Just realized my locale has changed correctly as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Buy.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUoUV.png), but results in my file manager are still the same..

What causing that?

Comment: Also: Which desktop environment?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thank you for your comment, I have edited all you requested.
I'm using PuTTY and 18.04 ubuntu

Comment: But PuTTY is a tool for remote access to a machine, right? Does the information you provide relate to your own machine or the one you access remotely?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have VPS server on hostinger, which runs Ubuntu OS, I'm accessing it remotely. Also I'm using VestaCP to upload the files to my server, but as you can see in the screenshot, it doesn't work

Comment: Hmm.. This sounds a bit over my head. Hopefully somebody else jumps in and helps.